# Different address gap between variables of same type

Tags: go, pointers

I've noticed there's **sometimes** increased gap between first and second int variables on some version of Go.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unsafe"
)

func main() {
    a := 7
    b := 8
    c := 9
    d := 10
    fmt.Printf("a's address is %v\n", &a)
    fmt.Printf("b's address is %v\n", &b)
    fmt.Printf("c's address is %v\n", &c)
    fmt.Printf("d's address is %v\n", &d)

    baSpan := uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&b)) - uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&a))
    cbSpan := uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&c)) - uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&b))
    dcSpan := uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&d)) - uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&c))

    // Go playground, Go 1.20 - Prints 8.
    // Go playground, Go dev branch - Sometimes prints 8, sometimes 24.
    // My machine, go1.20.4 windows/amd64 - Always prints 24.
    fmt.Printf("b-a span is %v\n", baSpan)

    fmt.Printf("c-b span is %v\n", cbSpan) // Prints 8
    fmt.Printf("d-c span is %v\n", dcSpan) // Prints 8
}
```

Go playground, go1.20 - https://go.dev/play/p/BJIVC1cQQoT

Go playground, Go dev - https://go.dev/play/p/BJIVC1cQQoT?v=gotip

The questions are:

1. Why does it print 24? What occupies remaining 16 bytes? *(considering `a` takes 8 bytes on 64-bit machine)*
2. Why is it random on Go playground?
3. HOW can we know what takes other 16 bytes? I suppose it can be done via inspecting an assembly code. Are there any other ways?

Comment: 1. Because that is the value. Undefined. 2. The playground is special for obvious reasons. 3. You cannot.

Comment: Heap allocations are made at runtime, and there is no specified location for each individual value. I could also get it to print `span` values like `507920` and `18446744073709043704`. There is no reason to try and inspect the relative addresses of your variables.

Comment: Why are you asking this? Since the question doesn't make much sense it seems likely to be an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info).

Answer (score 1):

Heap allocations are implementation and runtime dependent.

---

`x.go`:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unsafe"
)

func main() {
    a := 7
    b := 8
    c := 9
    d := 10
    fmt.Printf("a's address is %v\n", &a)
    fmt.Printf("b's address is %v\n", &b)
    fmt.Printf("c's address is %v\n", &c)
    fmt.Printf("d's address is %v\n", &d)

    baSpan := uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&b)) - uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&a))
    cbSpan := uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&c)) - uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&b))
    dcSpan := uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&d)) - uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&c))

    fmt.Printf("b-a span is %v\n", baSpan)
    fmt.Printf("c-b span is %v\n", cbSpan) 
    fmt.Printf("d-c span is %v\n", dcSpan) 
}
```

---

```
./x.go:9:2: moved to heap: a
./x.go:10:2: moved to heap: b
./x.go:11:2: moved to heap: c
./x.go:12:2: moved to heap: d
```

---

```
go1.20 version && go1.20 build -gcflags='-m' x.go && ./x
go version go1.20.7 linux/amd64
a's address is 0xc000018130
b's address is 0xc000018138
c's address is 0xc000018140
d's address is 0xc000018148
b-a span is 8
c-b span is 8
d-c span is 8
```

---

```
go1.21 version && go1.21 build -gcflags='-m' x.go && ./x
go version go1.21rc4 linux/amd64
a's address is 0xc00009c010
b's address is 0xc00009c018
c's address is 0xc00009c020
d's address is 0xc00009c028
b-a span is 8
c-b span is 8
d-c span is 8
```

---

```
go version && go build -gcflags='-m' x.go && ./x
go version devel go1.22-4e728e5121 Mon Aug 7 16:07:50 2023 +0000 X:loopvar linux/amd64
a's address is 0xc00009c010
b's address is 0xc00009c018
c's address is 0xc00009c020
d's address is 0xc00009c028
b-a span is 8
c-b span is 8
d-c span is 8
```

---

https://go.dev/play/p/HeAMYeBG1_o?v=go1.20

```
a's address is 0xc0000b2000
b's address is 0xc0000b2008
c's address is 0xc0000b2010
d's address is 0xc0000b2018
b-a span is 8
c-b span is 8
d-c span is 8
```

---

https://go.dev/play/p/HeAMYeBG1_o?v=gotip

```
a's address is 0xc000012028
b's address is 0xc000012040
c's address is 0xc000012048
d's address is 0xc000012050
b-a span is 24
c-b span is 8
d-c span is 8
```

---